# Scroll down to specific position after page refresh issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which works exactly as I need for refreshing a page using a submit button.

However I have added code in it to make it scroll down to a specific location after updating, the problem is, it scrolls down to the location, then springs back to the top of the page

any ideas why anybody please?

```
$(".visitpage").on('click', function() {
$('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader"></div><center><span style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;z-index:99999;"><b>Updating your results...</b></span></center></div>');
 setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
 $('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#search-results").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
function removeLoader() {
$("#loadingDiv").fadeOut(500, function() {
// fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
$("#loadingDiv").remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will surely need the scrollTo method of the window object in javascript. Then I would figure out how far down your element is by getting a reference for that object in pixels on the page. See [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) for how to do that, since part of your answer would be a duplicate question I will let you read it. And this article is helpful http://javascript.info/coordinates

```
window.scrollTo(500, 0);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong here; but if you created a div where you want the page to scroll, or if you have on there make sure it's named, then right after the refresh command add 
`window.location.href = "#YOURDIVTAGHERE";` so

So if this is the part of the page you want it to go down to:

```
<div id="search-results">
CONTENT
</div>
```

so then your JS code, maybe try:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(".visitpage").on('click', function(){
$('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader"></div><center><span style="font-size:22px;color:#000000;z-index:99999;"><b>Updating your results...</b></span></center></div>');
setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
});
function removeLoader(){
$( "#loadingDiv" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
// fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
$( "#loadingDiv" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
});
window.location.href = "#search-results";  
}
```